# If I use the Oathbow on targets other than my sworn enemy, do I have disadvantage on the attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons

The [Oathbow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/oathbow) (DMG, p. 183) allows you to declare one enemy as your sworn enemy until the next dawn, and its description adds:

> While your sworn enemy lives, you have disadvantage on attack rolls with all other weapons.

**If I use the Oathbow on targets other than my sworn enemy, do I have disadvantage on the attack?**

The way I read it, if my sworn enemy lives, and I choose to use the Oathbow to attack a target other than my sworn enemy (for example, battlefield conditions provide my sworn enemy total cover, so I start launching arrows at his minions until I can see my sworn enemy), I don't have disadvantage on the attack, because I only have disadvantage with all other weapons, not against all other targets.

Answer (score 7):

### No, you would not have disadvantage

The relevant text about the oathbow is this:

> When you make a ranged attack roll with this weapon against your sworn enemy, you have advantage on the roll. In addition, your target gains no benefit from cover, other than total cover, and you suffer no disadvantage due to long range. If the attack hits, your sworn enemy takes an extra 3d6 piercing damage. While your sworn enemy lives, you have disadvantage on attack rolls with all other weapons.

Nothing in there indicates that you would have disadvantage with the bow against other targets, only when using other weapons (even if you use them against your sworn enemy).